# multiple single page application in one using visual studio 2015 and angular 2

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, typescript1.8

I have been fidgeting with angularjs for a while just when i was getting used to it  then angular2 shows up. 
Using a combination of mvc routing and angular routing in angular 1 i created what i term multiple SPA in one app. I have my main menu at the top which uses the normal mvc routing technique to get around. then when i get to the specific page i do my sigle page stuff in there using angular routing. With angular 2 i cant seem to figure my way out. I havent sat down to dig into that. however going through the tour of heroes tutorials left me wondering how to implement such a solution.
I will appreciate any ideas

thanks

Julius

Comment: Great question.  This is the scenario we have and decided to stick with AngularJS.

Comment: Yeah well, I Had to do away completely with the mvc routing. The thing is I am in love with angular2. Typescript kind of sits very comfortably with me. I feel more organised